# YBOSS search API

Tags: oauth, yahoo, yahoo-api, yahoo-boss-api

I am using YBOSS V2 search API and it worked fine till a few days back.

All of a sudden it is throwing below error

```
 Valid AppID but requires registration
```

The URL is something like this

http://yboss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/web?format=json&market=en-us&q=%query%

I tried by creating a new APP, secret key and access key, but no luck

Any Ideas?